# How to send an image from one iPad to another?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, bonjour

I have been using these projects files ([SuperChat](https://code.google.com/p/iphonebusmiddleware/)), to try and set up a kind of messaging app. I have done this and it successfully works but I need to be able to send images across the two devices now.

I use this code to send a message to the other device:

```
[theTopic publishMessage:@"Message"];
```

How would I be able to send an image, as this only let's you send an NSString.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

convert the UIImage to a NSData and then to a base64EncodedString.
You will be able to use the same method to send the data across.

Only pitfall is if the sendMessage is a synchronous call, you might have to use GCD queues to send it asynchronously.

Comment: OK, thank you. Would you be able to post a mini example of how I convert it to a base64EncodedString to send it and then 'uncovert' it back again?